# How to detect version of PHPUnit

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm writing unit tests using an older version of PHPUnit (3.4) and thus can't use all supported assertions listed in manual of 3.5 and 3.6. Though I could reengineer tests for instant support in my environment here, I'd like to make my tests dependent on current version of PHPUnit, so that it's using assertsInstanceOf() as soon as my or any other one's testing environment is providing PHPUnit 3.5+.

I thought there would be some sort of constant automatically defined by PHPUnit, but I couldn't find any documentation on it.

Is there any way of achieving this without requiring definition of constant when calling on command line?

Comment: @zerkms:Trying to stay in sync with my distro. Expecting others running tests on their systems and thus probably not using latest software.

Comment: @Marc B: I want to implement it inside code, since I'm invoking all tests with "phpunit <relative-pathname-to-folder-with-test-class-files>" and then requiring some tests to skip or switch behaviour depending on used phpunit version ... some sort of conditional coding.

Comment: @zerkms it is not your problem

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can get the version of PHPUnit running using the [`\PHPUnit\Runner\Version` <sup>*[git]*</sup>](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/9.5.19/src/Runner/Version.php) class and its static `id()` method:

```
$phpUnitVersion = \PHPUnit\Runner\Version::id(); # 9.5.19
```

And based on that - halt your tests execution or do whatever you want.

---

Before PHPUnit fully switched to PHP namespaces (PHPUnit 6), the old class-name was [`PHPUnit_Runner_Version` <sup>*[git]*</sup>](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/3.5.15/PHPUnit/Runner/Version.php).

Comment: I'd do if stackoverflow.com would allow me to do so (keyword: badges).

Answer (score 18):

Works on mac:

```
phpunit --version
```

@Marc B

Comment: Works on Linux as well

Comment: Works on Windows as well

Comment: This CLI helpful command doesn't depend on the platform. Apparently, it was introduced on [version 4.7.5](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/f6701ef3faea759acd1910a7751d8d102a7fd5bc/src/Runner/Version.php). Or at least that´s what git history shows. I recommend to look for other methods programmatically.

Answer (score 8):

You can add [an annotation](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/incomplete-and-skipped-tests.html#incomplete-and-skipped-tests.skipping-tests-using-requires) before the test:

```
/**
 * @requires PHPUnit 3.7.32
 */
function testRequiringCertainPHPUnit() {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

2020 Solution

```php
use PHPUnit\Runner\Version as PHPUnitVersion;

die(PHP_EOL . PHPUnitVersion::id() . PHP_EOL); // 9.2.6
die(PHP_EOL . PHPUnitVersion::series() . PHP_EOL); // 9.2
die(PHP_EOL . explode('.', PHPUnitVersion::id())[0] . PHP_EOL); // 9
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers above are more likely to match your case but if you:

1. Want to use the terminal.
2. You have projects with different versions of PHPunit and want to check specific one.

Go to the home directory of your PHPunit installation (most likely *vendor*) and run:

```
egrep -r "Version.*\('.*'" phpunit/phpunit/src/Runner/Version.php --include=*.php --color
```